# Can not enter debug mode in python Vscode that comes with Anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, visual-studio-code, anaconda

**Ways to reproduce:**

[My helloworld code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOS0F.png)

[launch.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ky6m.png)

[settings.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RKJS.png)

**Expected behavior:**

After I click the debug icon(appears like a spider) and then choose 'python current file' in the configuration drop-down menu, and then click green arrow to start debug, I should see the program pause at the first line.

**Observed behavior:**

[The system cannot find path specified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBhiK.png)

**Other information that might be useful:**

OS: windows7 service pack 1

Anacodna Version: Anaconda3-5.1.0-Windows-x86_64

Vscode version: 1.22.2